# How can add different colour for each worksheet in excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When you have multiple worksheets in a workbook, you usually click on a sheet's name at the bottom of the page to view it. 
My question is then to know, if that "button" containing the sheet's name can take a color such as blue, green and so on.

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(); 
    CTColor color = CTColor.Factory.newInstance(); 
    color.setIndexed(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex()); 
    sheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetPr().setTabColor(color);
```

I have tried above but no use

```
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {

        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("1e");



        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("1econtent");
        XSSFFont font = wb.createFont();
        font.setFontHeightInPoints((short) 15);
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());

        How can I add different colours sheet and sheet1 in workbook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do it as follows:

```
sheet.setTabColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
```

Please check https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html for more details.

**EDIT:**

Please do it as follows with the latest version of Apache POI:

```
byte[] rgb=DefaultIndexedColorMap.getDefaultRGB(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
sheet.setTabColor(new XSSFColor(rgb,null));
```

Comment: still getting error if I use as follows

sheet.setTabColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex())

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash: Whether this is correct depends on the `apache poi` version. Up to version `3.16` there was `public void setTabColor(int colorIndex)` and the `colorIndex` could be `IndexedColors.RED.getIndex()`. But that was removed in version `3.17`. Now in current versions there is only `public void setTabColor(XSSFColor color)`. So a `XSSFColor` must be used as parameter here.

Comment: Error is : The method setTabColor(XSSFColor) in the type XSSFSheet is not applicable for the arguments (short)

Comment: even I tried like sheet.setTabColor(0); no use again same error as specified

Comment: Can anyone help me out

Comment: Thank you  Arvind Kumar Avinash updated answer is working fine